# Gui viewer for RocksDb sst files

Tags: apache-kafka, apache-kafka-streams, rocksdb, rocks

I'm working with Kafka that save the data into rocksdb.

Now I want to have a look at the db keys and values that created by Kafka.
I downloaded FastNoSQL and tried but failed.

The folder contains:

- .sst files
- .log files
- CURRENT file
- IDENTITY file
- LOCK file
- LOG files
- MANIFEST files
- OPTIONS files

How can I watch the values?

Answer (score 1):

It looks like the reason you have data stored in RocksDB files is because you are using Apache Kafka's Streams API.  If so, then you can use Kafka's [interactive queries](http://docs.confluent.io/current/streams/developer-guide.html#interactive-queries) feature to look into your data.

If, however, you want to interact directly with the local RocksDB files, you need to use other tools.  I don't have experience with any GUIs for RocksDB, but perhaps answers from other SO folks can cover those.